# Do we need MathJax?

Tags: discussion

In [an answer involving calculation](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1403/99), the math is quite ugly. Yes, most of the questions asked here won't need an integration, but maybe someday, when the site proliferates enough (hope so), there is a need to add math formular so that advance users can write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt the overall need for it will justify the attendant overhead, and this is from someone who is likely in the category of folks who would write something down in equation form.

Comment: sorry, I read your answer many times but still don't understand it (I'm not an English native). I know that you are disagree with this, but can you rephrase your answer?

Comment: Basically, MathJax costs resources to have - having enabled it on my own site, it has overhead in terms of the page load speed etc. My assertion is that the cost is not likely to be outweighed by the benefit of occasionally writing pretty math - and that's from someone who *does* appreciate the value of pretty math.

Comment: I get it now. You can add this to your answer.